# A query to calculate columns average for different parameters using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains two chemicals measurements at the same location for each year (not necessary every month though). I want the annual average for each chemical for each location.  The other columns should stay the same without change. 
The original table looks like this:

```
Location    parameter   value   date    …   …
A       chloride    1   1/2001  …   …
A       chloride    2   2/2001  …   …
A       chloride    3   3/2001  …   …
A       sodium      5   1/2001  …   …
A       sodium      6   2/2001  …   …
A       sodium      7   3/2001  …   …
B       chloride    10  1/2002  …   …
B       chloride    12  2/2002  …   …
B       chloride    13  3/2002  …   …
B       sodium      4   1/2002  …   …
B       sodium      2   2/2002  …   …
B       sodium      7   3/2002  …   …
.
.
.
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Location    parameter      value    date    …   …
A       chloride    2       2001    …   …
A       sodium      6       2001    …   …
B       chloride    11.7    2002    …   …
B       sodium      4.3     2002    …   …
.
.
.
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server management Studio 2014. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the average and year functions. You tagged both MySQL and SQL Server, so I am assuming you are using SQL Server. Try:

```
SELECT
    Location
    ,parameter
    ,AVG(value)
    ,YEAR(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY    
    Location
    ,parameter
    ,YEAR(date)
```

Add any additional columns you want included. This will give you a distinct list of the columns you are not aggregating as well as the aggregated column (in this case, the average value).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT
Location
,Parameter
,avg(value)
,year(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY
Location
,Parameter
,Year(date)
```